# Dynamic Expresso: Unknown identifier IDictionary

Tags: dynamic-expresso

I am trying to get dynamic expresso to interpret this line of code:

```
(((IDictionary<string, object>)o)["Diesel % in oil"].ToString().StartsWith("<") ? ((IDictionary<string, object>)o)["Diesel % in oil"].ToString().Replace("<", String.Empty) : ((IDictionary<string, object>)o)["Diesel % in oil"].ToString())
```

When it executes I get the following exception `Unknown identifier 'IDictionary' (at index 3).`

I am testing for a "<" at the start and then replacing all instances of the "<" (excuse the terrible key name - out of my control that one!).

I have tried adding `typeof(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>)` as a reference to the interpreter object, but no joy.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: I suggest to post the question on github, where we are more active: https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso/issues . But I suspect that `IDictionary` is not know as type, but you can add it.

Comment: @DavideIcardi Will do! I posted on SO as that's what was suggested in the wiki [https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso/wiki](https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso/wiki)